# How to display Table header in the multiple pages if we cannot include the Table header either in "Header or Footer"

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

How to display Table header in the multiple pages if we cannot include the Table header either in "Page Header or Footer" . Basically i dont want the table header to display in the first page because its already there in the the body.

i have tried putting table header in the Page header then tried to hide it with

=iif(Globals!PageNumber = 1, TRUE, FALSE)

it works, But its destroying my other information(Like images and Report Name) in the Page Header by putting everything on the left side (No Idea why).

Please help me fix this.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what you have now and what you want to achieve. At the moment the it's not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repeat tablix header in each of the page in SSRS report than you can do it by opening the tablix property and check Row headers and column headers section just like below image

[image]

Also if you want to repeat (fix) you header section in scroll then click on tablix and in  Column Groups select Advanced mode just like below image

[image]

inside the advanced mode there will be all columns will be loaded just like below image

[image]

In row group select static option as selected in image and open property window by clicking F4 in that select **FixedData** as true just like below image

[image]

it will fix header on scroll too just like we fix column in Excel.